# Cocos2d-x Admob on iOS

Tags: ios, admob, cocos2d-x

I want to add admob "smart banners" at the bottom of the portrait screen. But the code show the adds at the top of screen. Here is my code

```
    cocos2d::CCSize size = cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
            CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(size.width,0.0);
    bannerView_ = [[[GADBannerView alloc]
                      initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
                      origin:origin] autorelease];
```

No matter how I change the origin the ads are showing at the top of the screen. Any help is highly appriciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how I’ve achieved to show ad on bottom of the screen.

```
    GADBannerView* bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];

//For Positioning
    float winHeight = viewController.view.frame.size.height;
    float winWidth = viewController.view.frame.size.width;
    //BannerView y-center is half of it's total height, and co-ordinates have to be calculated with TOP-Left as (0,0). Multiplied by 0.5 for y-center of banner view.
    bannerView_.center=CGPointMake(winWidth/2, winHeight - 0.50 * bannerView_.frame.size.height);

    //bannerView_.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerView_.rootViewController = viewController;
    [viewController.view addSubview:bannerView_];




GADRequest * request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,                               // Simulator
                       nil];
// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way : I create the banner without origin. Then when the ad is loaded, the `- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView` delegate method gets fired, and in it I animate the banner to slide down from the top of the screen. Here is the code :

```
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView {

    self.adBannerView = bannerView;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^
         {
             CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

             CGRect frame = self.adBannerView.frame;

             frame.origin.y = 0;

             self.adBannerView.frame = frame;
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
         }];
}
```